# pysmb copy file from Ubuntu to Windows network share folder

Tags: python, samba, pysmb

From Ubuntu I am able to use pysmb to connect to a Windows network share and then list off all available shares and list all files and folders of the root of that share but nothing further down the tree.  I need to access a folder 5 folder levels into the Shared path to copy a file to that location and cannot get past the root level of the file share.

I have tried to use forward slashes and backward slashes (single and double) between the paths and tried including and excluding the trailing slashes either way.  I have tried only 1 level in and every one in between as well.

```py
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

userid = 'myid'
password = 'mypassword'
client = 'clientMachine'
remote = 'remoteMachine'
server_ip = '5.5.5.5'

conn = SMBConnection(userid, password, client, remote, domain='MYDOM',use_ntlmv2 = True)
assert conn.connect(server_ip, 139)
sharelist = conn.listShares()
for s in sharelist:
    print(s.name)
filelist = conn.listPath('Shared','/')
for f in filelist:
    print(f.filename)

conn.close()
```

If I include any other path in the listPath call other than '/' I get the path is not found even though the paths I am trying are listed in the print statement:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testsmb.py", line 14, in <module>
    filelist = conn.listPath('Shared', '/Corp/')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smb/SMBConnection.py", line 202, in listPath
    self._pollForNetBIOSPacket(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smb/SMBConnection.py", line 630, in _pollForNetBIOSPacket
    self.feedData(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nmb/base.py", line 54, in feedData
    self._processNMBSessionPacket(self.data_nmb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nmb/base.py", line 75, in _processNMBSessionPacket
    self.onNMBSessionMessage(packet.flags, packet.data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smb/base.py", line 145, in onNMBSessionMessage
    if self._updateState(self.smb_message):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smb/base.py", line 339, in _updateState_SMB2
    req.callback(message, **req.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smb/base.py", line 638, in createCB
    errback(OperationFailure('Failed to list %s on %s: Unable to open directory' % ( path, service_name ), messages_history))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smb/SMBConnection.py", line 196, in eb
    raise failure
smb.smb_structs.OperationFailure: Failed to list Corp on Shared: Unable to open directory
```

I need to get into a share that is nested here:

```
//remotemachine/Shared/Corp/Futher/Futher with Space/Yet another Space/Test
```

I can see all the shares, I can even see the files and folders in each shares root level but no further in.  I have permissions in all levels, what am I missing?

Comment: Did you get any response or the solution to this?